# WPF getting object inside Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

Problem. I don't know how to access the objects inside the passed Window Object from my method.

```
void MyMethod(Window myWindow){
     myWindow. <--- "I have an Progress bar inside this object that I believe has been passed. But don't know how to access it".




}
```

I can also try to use the current Application class library from System.Windows but the problem is still the same, I just don't know how to reference the objects that is inside the window.

```
void MyMethod(){
     ProgressBar myprogressbarInsidetheApp = Application.Current.MainWindow <----- I am lost. Please help.

}
```

Comment: the API QR made by other company, needs to have this object sent. I know I am not suppose to do that, but the API is forcing us to. Because the machine have their own implementation of things we can't control. Well the other way that I asked, is pretty much the same on what you are trying to imply. Application.Current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid passing a reference to the `Window`, but if you have some constraint that's forcing you too, then you'll need to cast it to your *specific* `Window` before you can access any elements on it.

If this was your window, named "MainWindow":

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Name="MyProgressBar" Value="30" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You'd have to cast it like this:

```
void MyMethod(Window myWindow)
{
    var pb = ((MainWindow)myWindow).MyProgressBar;

    // do something with "pb"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Grant. How about accessing it the proper way or using the Application.Current way? As an update of the answer?

Comment: make sense. On a regular part of programming. But I am hindered with this API problem. Thank you for the answer Grant.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be doing this but if you absolutely insist...use the [WPF Tree Visualizer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/29/using-the-wpf-tree-visualizer/) to determine the name of the child element you are trying to access and then use `window.FindName("the_elements_name");` to get a reference object. If the element doesn't have a name then you'll need to [navigate the entire visual tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523139/find-control-in-the-visual-tree) looking for an element of the required type.