# Identify and find element in XAML tree by XPath

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xpath, uwp

Is there any possibility to use XPath in order to identify each XAML element in running application?

For example if I have following XAML structure.

```
<Page>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I would like to know XPath of the second button for instance and when I have it, I would like to retrieve the button thanks to XPath afterwards.

I know that I can work with XPath without any problems if I have `XmlDocument` but I would like to achieve the same stuff with elements from running application if it is possible.

Comment: Can you show code that you'd like to write? Not very clear what "the same stuff with elements from running application" means...

Comment: Sounds like a pretty painful way to go. If you are going to want to access controls from the code-behind it makes sense to name them (x:Name="someName") and then access them based on their name ( Button btn = (Button)this.FindName("someName"); )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I mean when I click on the second button I would like to get "/Page/StackPanel/Button[index]". Afterwards thanks to XPath expression I would like to find the button.

Comment: @Asnivor Probably painful, however, I am curious whether it is possible or not (without naming).

Comment: You can... but I don't believe there is an existing implementation. If you really want to make one - read on XPathNavigator which was designed to allow XPath navigation over arbitrary trees... But this approach never took off to my knowledge - so hard to find any useful samples/implementations.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for your feedback. If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no such XAML structure to apply an XPath on at runtime. The XAML parser will parse your XAML markup and create a tree of elements that make up the user interface that you see on the screen.

So if you need to find the second button in a StackPanel once it has been constructed at runtime you should either look directly in the StackPanel's Children collection:

```
Button secondButton = sp.Children[1] as Button;
```

...or use the VisualTreeHelper class to find it in the visual tree: [Find control in the visual tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523139/find-control-in-the-visual-tree)