# Get UserControl inside tabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datatemplate, tabitem

I have a `TabControl`, with a template, like so :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" x:Name="tabs">
  <TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate" x:Name="contentTemplate" >
      <other:MyUserControl x:Name="mUserControl"  CustomData="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource contentTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
  </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

`MyItems` is an `ObservableCollection` of custom objects.
When I call `tabs.SelectedContent` it returns an item.

I would like to get the UserControl `MyUserControl` contained in the `contentTemplate` DataTemplate.

Because `mUserControl` is in a template, I can't call it like `mUserControl.doSomething()`.

I tried to use the templates "FindName" function :

```
ControlTemplate dt = tabs.Template;
MyUserControl mControl = (MyUserControl)dt.FindName("mUserControl", tabs);
```

But it returns null.

I would like to access the `MyUserControl` object to call a function that will change it's state (show a control and hide another one). 
This happens when the user clicks on a MenuItem (owned by the MainWindow), but the affected widget is the UserControl.

So, how do I get a reference to the `MyUserControl` object ?

Comment: Just a note but with a proper (MVVM) design you shouldn't want this. It is so difficult because you are breaking Model/View separation.

Comment: How could I wrote this in a proper way wihtout breaking the Model/view separation ?

Comment: I agree that this is almost certainly not the best approach. Include a description of the result you are trying to achieve and we may be able to suggest a better solution

Comment: I updated the description, hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse your Visual tree from your TabControl deeper inside and you can get all your user controls which are inside it.

You should read about visual tree or answers like this:
[Find control in the visual tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523139/find-control-in-the-visual-tree)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for, thank you very much